# Returning a C string in a constexpr function: why no warning from the compiler?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, c-strings, string-literals

Consider the following code:

```
constexpr auto f()
{
    auto str = "Hello World!";
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    static constexpr auto str = f();
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is that normal that my compiler does not display any warning? Is it defined behavior? Do I have the guarantee that the program will display `"Hello World!"`? I would expect the `"Hello World!"` not to live beyond the scope of the function...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++ [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) have [static storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and live as long as the program runs. So, a pointer to a string literal returned from `f` is always valid. No allocation or deallocation is involved.

Note that string literals have type `const char[N]`, which in your case decays to `const char *` due to `auto` type deduction. If your intent was to use `std::string`, you can directly construct it

```
auto str = std::string("Hello World!");
```

or use [`operator""s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s):

```
using std::string_literals;
auto str = "Hello World!"s;
```

However, since `std::string` is not a literal type, this values [cannot be `constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) anymore.

Comment: "string literals have type `const char *`" They don't.

Comment: @T.C. `const char` array of concrete length?

Answer (score 5):

That's the *second effect* of auto. What you think it is, is not always what the compiler decides. This can leads to wrong programmer expectation - the rule is here *compiler always win*.

The fact here is that `str` is a `const char *` to a (static storage duration) string litteral. It can be fully determined at build time, so it is a valid constexpr.